# how to run the perl script in the directory which i specify while running the script in the command line

Tags: perl

How to run the perl script in the directory which i specify while running the script in the command line
Example:

```
./scriptname -rd run
```

My script should go to directory name run and it should run there?

Answer (score 4):

Do a `chdir()` in your Perl script.

cf http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to chdir to the directory before running the script:

```
dir=$(readlink -f .)
cd run
"$dir"/scriptname
```